# Passing string variables to method used by JSP

Tags: java, string

I have the following `String` method in a Java class:

```
public String getStudentId(Id userId) throws Exception {
    String sid = null;

    try {
        UserDbLoader userDbLoader = UserDbLoader.Default.getInstance();   
        User ul = userDbLoader.loadById(userId);                                
        sid = ul.getStudentId();

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("***Debug Section 1***");
        System.out.println("Student ID: " + sid); 
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }

    return sid; 
}
```

And I want to pass the variable `sid` to the next `String` method which uses `dbcp2` to connect to a DB to return a corresponding value: `pidm`

The second String method is:

```
public String dbQuery(String sid) {

    String student_id = sid;      
    String pdTemp = null;

    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
        BasicDataSource bds = MapSource.getInstance().getBds();
        connection = bds.getConnection();

        statement = connection.prepareStatement("select pidm from b21_toolbar_timetable_mapping where student_id = ?"); 
        statement.setObject(1, student_id);                 
        rs = statement.executeQuery(); 

        while (rs.next()) {
          pdTemp = rs.getNString("pidm"); 
        }

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("**** Debug Section 2 ***");
        System.out.println("**** SID: " + sid);
        System.out.println("**** student_id: " + student_id);
        System.out.println("**** PIDM: " + pdTemp);                 
    } 
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally {
        try {
            if (rs != null)
                rs.close();
            if (statement != null)
                statement.close();
            if (connection != null)
                connection.close();
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return pdTemp;
}
```

My question is what have am I missing? The `sid` variable is not passing through to the `try` statement in `dbQuery` so the Debug Section 2 statements  contain no outputs.

Comment: where's the dbQuery call?

Comment: the second string method is called dbQuery. The class containing the actual call to the DB I have not included here as I know the connection to the DB is being made. I have proved this using a main method call.

Comment: Have you tried debugging ?

Comment: @Aigloun Yes. The Debug Statements are my attempt to examine the code. This is written with an IDE and compiles and runs, the debug statements output into either the console or the JSP system logs. Using a main method the code outputs correctly. But running within the system - the statements are blank.

Comment: I'm talking about running your code in debug mode and inspecting exactly what's happening and where is it failing

Comment: Yes I have run in debug mode - no errors generated.

Comment: Resolved. There was an error in my JSP calling these two methods.